# Service runs in Emulator but gives sqliteError in Android Device

Tags: android, cordova, service

I am trying to create a service in which i want to upload image to server in background but when try to execute it in the emulator ti runs perfectly but when i try to run the same in device it gives sqlite lite error. The code is return in the phonegap but the service code is return in native.
here is the logacat Error:

```
02-24 13:04:21.988: I/System.out(1160): call after 2 minutes
02-24 13:04:21.992: I/System.out(1160): Your connection succeed
02-24 13:04:21.992: I/System.out(1160): Check Database Exist or not?
02-24 13:04:21.992: I/(1160): database exists
02-24 13:04:21.996: I/System.out(1160): my path in db helper data/data/com.sacpl.nesso`/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db
02-24 13:04:21.996: I/System.out(1160): path of the database: /data/data/com.sacpl.nesso/databases/0000000000000001.db
02-24 13:04:21.996: I/System.out(1160): Database already Exist
02-24 13:04:21.996: I/(1160): --------------------Call get master `Entry----------------------
02-24 13:04:22.000: I/Database(1160): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: android_metadata
02-24 13:04:22.000: E/Database(1160): SELECT locale FROM android_metadata failed
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1987)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1855)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at com.sacpl.nesso.MyService.getNewMasterEntry(MyService.java:441)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at com.sacpl.nesso.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:111)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2043)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-24 13:04:22.007: E/Database(1160):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1987)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1855)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at com.sacpl.nesso.MyService.getNewMasterEntry(MyService.java:441)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at com.sacpl.nesso.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:111)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2043)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-24 13:04:22.007: W/System.err(1160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-24 13:04:22.015: W/System.err(1160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-24 13:04:22.015: W/System.err(1160):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any Idea is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you created the metadata table? Please refer here: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: open db before accessing

Comment: i am not coping the database file I just providing the path of the database file created app_database/file__0 folder.

Comment: but its working properly in the emulator.